# Another way to set DB::deep?

Tags: perl, debugging

When debugging complex code using standart Perl debugger in NonStop mode [sometimes we get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562552/how-do-i-get-the-perl-debugger-to-not-stop-at-100-levels-deep-in-subroutine-cal) `100 levels deep in subroutine calls` error.

Is there another way to set `$DB::deep` variable, without touching code ?

I tried to use [dumpDepth](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html#dumpDepth) option, but seems like it's not available in NonStop mode.

I know about `perl -MPerlIO='via;$DB::deep=500'` hack, but it's not working with perl version >= 5.20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `~/.perldb` file with

```
$DB::deep=500
```

Set permissions on this file to something secure (0444 or 0644) so you don't get this admonishment:

> perldb: Must not source insecure rcfile /Users/mob/.perldb.
>           You or the superuser must be the owner, and it must not 
>           be writable by anyone but its owner.

Comment: In this case, "must not" means "did not" - the file won't be read and executed unless the permissions are correct.